# GAP: How to find a (possibly non-minimal) transitive representation of a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, galois-theory, gap

I've recently fell in love with Galois Theory again and in an attempt to categorize how one could determine the Galois group of small-degree irreducible polynomials, I stumbled upon this small problem using GAP.

Since any Galois group of an $k$-degree polynomial must be a transitive subgroup of the symmetric group $S_k$, it seems natural enough that we interpret it as some permutation subgroup of $S_k$, i.e. some set of permutations on $k$ elements. As it turns out, some subgroups are intransitive for the "smallest" inclusion in $S_k$, as can be seen by the cyclic group $C_6$ having the representation
$$C_6 \cong \langle (1,2),(3,4,5)\rangle \leq S_5$$
being intransitive over $5$ elements. In contrast, we have that
$$C_6 \cong \langle (1,2,3,4,5,6)\rangle \leq S_6$$
*is* a transitive group on $6$ elements, i.e. the minimal representation on $5$ elements does not actually imply anything about the transitivity in another context. A similar thing happens with $D_{6} \leq S_5$ being intransitive but $D_{6} \leq S_6$ being transitive on their respective number of elements.

To clearly illustrate the problem, I implemented the example above in GAP:

```
gap> g:=SmallGroup(6,2)
> ;; iso := Image(MinimalFaithfulPermutationRepresentation(g))
> ; StructureDescription(g)
> ; Transitivity(iso,[1..6])
> ;
Group([(1,2),(3,4,5)])
"C6"
0

gap> g:=Group([(1,2,3,4,5,6)])
> ; StructureDescription(g)
> ; Transitivity(g,[1..6])
> ;
Group([(1,2,3,4,5,6)])
"C6"
1
```

You can see that while both permutation groups represent $C_6$ in some way, there is a problem with GAP choosing a representation that is "too small".

Thus, my question is the following:

> Given a finite group $G$ such that there exists some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $G \leq S_k$, how can I use GAP to find a *transitive* permutation subgroup $H \leq S_l$ such that $H \cong G$ for **arbitrary** $l \geq k$?

Thank you to James in the comments for supplying a way of how to deal with the different transitive representations! I will try to implement it and if everything works, I will gladly accept an answer from you or the other commenters.

Comment: Are you looking for a faithful and *transitive* permutation representation of minimal degree?  If the group is abelian or generalised quaternion, then you cannot do better than the regular representation.  Otherwise, you could look for a core-free subgroup of smallest index among representatives of the conjugacy classes of subgroups.  The representation of the group on the cosets of such a subgroup is such a transitive faithful action of smallest degree.

Comment: @James Hm, I don't think that would be enough, since for example $S_5$ acts transitively on 5 *and* 6 elements, meaning it could be the Galois group of quintics and sextics (and it is). In this case, the interpretation of GAP matters for the output of the Transitivity function.

Comment: How do you get $D_{12}$ as a subgroup of $S_6$? You need $n\ge7$ to find elements of order twelve in $S_n$.

Comment: @TheOutZ Yes, $S_5$ has a Frobenius subgroup of index $6$ that is core-free.  So are you looking for *all* the faithful and transitive permutation representations of your group?  In that case, you can take all the coset actions on core-free subgroups (one from each conjugacy class of core-free subgroups).  Every faithful transitive representation is equivalent to one of those.  For $S_5$, there are $17$ of them, ranging from the smallest degree $5$ (the natural representation on $5$ points) up to the regular representation of degree $120$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There are differing conventions regarding dihedral groups. I think here $D_{12}$ is the dihedral group of order $12$.

Comment: @TheOutZ There is a lot of context, but the question is still unclear (to me at least). It would be helpful if you could state the actual question explicitly at some point.

Comment: Yes please state the question clearly and concisely!

Comment: @DerekHolt I've edited my question accordingly. Since I had a hard time figuring out what the confusion was, I hope that I have now made my question clear enough.

Comment: I still don't really understand the question. If you can find $G \le S_k$ then, since $S_k < S_l$ for all $l > k$, you aleady have $G < S_l$. In fact GAP identifies $S_k$ acting on $[1..k]$ with the subgroup of $S_l$ that fixes all points $j$ with $k < j \le l$, so you don't have to anything at all in GAP. Are you saying that you want to find all subgroups of $S_l$ that are isomorphic to $G$? That would be difficult!

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you, I'm a bit dense today, just realised that on the way home too. My bad. I will edit my question accordingly to only account for the additional constraint of "transitive representation in $S_n$".

Comment: @James After some bit of thought - yes, that should be exactly what I need, thank you! I will implement it in a moment and will gladly accept a comment-copy-pasted answer from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every transitive permutation representation of our group $G$ is equivalent to the action of $G$ on the cosets of some subgroup $H$ (the stabiliser of any point).  The kernel of the action is the core $H_G$ of $H$ in $G$ (that is, the intersection of all the conjugates of $H$ in $G$).  So, for the representation to be faithful, we need to consider core-free subgroups $H$, those with $H_G = 1$.  For some groups, such as abelian groups, the only faithful transitive permutation representation is the regular one (with $H$ itself being trivial).  Therefore, in order to find all the transitive faithful permutation representations, we need to consider all the core-free subgroups $H$ of $G$.  Taking one representative from each conjugacy class of core-free subgroups of $G$ will produce all the faithful transitive permutation representations of $G$.

Something like the following should work.

```
 AllTransReps := function( G )
    local   L;
    if not IsFinite( G ) then
            Error( "group must be finite" );
    fi;
    if IsAbelian( G ) then
            # We could also check for a quaternion group.
            return [ Image( RegularActionHomomorphism( G ) ) ];
    else
            # Get a representative from each conjugacy class of subgroups.
            L := List( ConjugacyClassesSubgroups( G ), Representative );
            # Restrict to those that are core-free.
            L := Filtered( L, H -> Size( Core( G, H ) ) = 1 );
            # Produce the action of G on the cosets of each subgroup.
            return List( L, H -> Image( FactorCosetAction( G, H ) ) );
    fi;
end;;
```

Try it out on a couple of examples:

```
gap> T := AllTransReps( SymmetricGroup( 5 ) );;
gap> ForAll( T, IsTransitive );
true
gap> Set( T, IdSmallGroup );
[ [ 120, 34 ] ]
gap> T := AllTransReps( SmallGroup( 8, 5 ) );
[ Group([ (1,2)(3,5)(4,6)(7,8), (1,3)(2,5)(4,7)(6,8), (1,4)(2,6)(3,7)(5,8) ]) ]
gap> ForAll( T, IsTransitive );
true
gap> List( T, IdSmallGroup );
[ [ 8, 5 ] ]
```

Comment: Yup, that looks right, figured the implementation out on my own yesterday, but it is really interesting to see how you do it :).

Comment: Subgroups equivalent under (outer) automorphism will yield equivalent permutation representations.